# Source code migration from TFS 2013 to Azure Devops service

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Please suggest if someone has experience of migrating source code of 3-4 applications (including their dev, stage & production environment) from TFS to Azure Devops into Git repository & then build the CI/CD pipeline. We don't require work items or history to be migrated.

Can someone give high level steps & what would be approach for migration?

On premise TFS service is TFS 2013 & source code is to be migrated to Azure Devops services. Currently they are using TFVC. Also these are .net applications. One of the application is having around 9.5 GB of data to be migrated. Kindly advice the process and tools which could help with code migration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are working on TFVC, you need to use a third-party tool **[GIT-TFS](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs)**.

The Git-TFS tool is a two-way bridge between Team Foundation Version Control and Git, and can be used to perform a migration. Git-TFS is appropriate if you want to attempt a migration with full history, more than the 180 days that the Import tool supports, or if you want to attempt a migration that includes multiple branches and merge relationships.

You simply need to go through the following five steps to migrate your TFCV repo to Git.

1. Step 1: Install git-tfs. There are multiple tools to migrate from
   TFVC to Git. ...
2. Step 2: Export to local Git Repo. ...
3. Step 3: Cleanup New Git Repository. ...
4. Step 4: Create new Git Repo in TFS. ...
5. Step 5: Initial Commit to Git Repo.

More details please take a look at this blog-- [Migrate From TFVC To Git – 5 Simple Steps](https://www.scrum-tips.com/2018/08/28/migrate-from-tfvc-to-git/)

Comment: Thanks for the details. its quite useful.

Comment: not sure how can i do this.. unable to find option to mark it as an answer..pls suggest.